# How to enable NAT on private GKE in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, nat

I want to download some packages from the internet inside the pod for debugging purposes. By default, this is not allowed in private GKE as the nodes only have private IPs.

Kindly provide all the steps to perform to enable NAT?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example

Answer (score 0):

You can follow instructions provided in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example) as it was suggested by *@LundinCast* or 3rd party [example](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-cloud-nat-with-gke-cluster-c82364546d9e) of using [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) with GKE Cluster, but I found useful for myself this [article](https://blog.softwaremill.com/setting-up-the-private-kubernetes-cluster-on-gke-the-working-one-e155ca18c113) with an example of temporally solution for access to the Internet.

Comment: What about another Medium article and official documentation? If you've got any errors please update your post with your steps and errors.